# Has Martin commented on the increased crudity in the TV series?

Tags: game-of-thrones

It's a popular claim that the TV series *Game of Thrones* has a lot more nudity, sex, graphic violence and swearing than are found in the novels (which nobody says are squeaky clean, but the claim is that the difference is clearly noticeable). Usually implied is that this is because of superficial marketing matters (i.e. "sex, swearing and violence sells") instead of artistic choices in portrayal of the story.

I gather that George R. R. Martin has been heavily involved with the development of the TV series, and often comments publicly about the work which he's doing.

**Has he made any comments about this difference?** If so, were these just a passing notice, approval, disapproval, etc.?

Comment: I've heard that nudity and sex is intended to attract the female audience. It's swords and dragons that attract the guys. This question is really more about TV-series and the TV-industry than it is about fantasy or GRRM/ASOIAF.

Comment: There are puerile audiences worldwide, coming from the UK and living in the USA, I would hardly think that the USA was the worse of the two countries on that front.  I bet the worldwide market for HBO series exceeds the 'domestic' market.

Comment: @TLP no, the question isn't about why the TV show differs in this respect, it's about what the creator of this *fantasy* series has said about those differences.

Comment: @iandotkelly the US has much stricter regulations about what can be shown on publicly-owned spectrum than most other countries (shows from other countries are often edited before they can show in the US). The common want-what-you-don't-have behaviour leads to US audiences wanting more HBO-style programming.  A question about the nature of these differences, however, isn't on-topic here.

Comment: Many more things in the book are wholly un-airable (on any station); viz. nude minors.

Comment: I made a significant edit to the question, restating the factual statement of "there is more violence etc." as only a popular claim. That was because I don't think the discussion whether that is true or not is relevant to the question (what GRRM thinks about it). I didn't intend to attack the author's point of view with my edit, only to keep the focus on what's being asked. The truth of the claim itself is disputed, and discussing that should really be it's own question.

Comment: @IlariKajaste Good edit. I'm one who disputes that the "crudity" is increased. Yes, there are new scenes introduced that seem to be just for gratuitous "T&A", but there are also quite a few similar scenes from the books that do not make it to the show.  In fact, sex, violence, and profanity are so commonplace in the books that significantly increasing the amount would likely push the show into the realms of x-rated.

Comment: @Beofett Agreed! The books are pretty violent and sexually explicit. Other than the fact the TV series, being a visual medium, has to _show_ things the books _tell_, I don't think they are different in their "crudity".

Comment: @AndresF. I don't understand what you mean... Of course it's possible to comment on things that might or might not be true. People do it all the time. The claim does exist whether or not it's true. Maybe I misunderstand you in some way?

Comment: @IlariKajaste You are right. I thought it made sense when I wrote it :P Please disregard my comment; I've deleted it.

Comment: I don’t know, but they definitely had more Crudités on set while filming than I had at home while reading.  ;)

Answer (score 16):

GRRM has been in the TV-industry for a long time, I'm fairly sure that he would go with the flow and not speak out against his series. I found [this interview](http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/ustv/s151/game-of-thrones/news/a329509/game-of-thrones-not-sexist-says-author-george-r-r-martin.html) where he claims:

> "One of the reasons I wanted to do this [series] with HBO is that I
>   wanted to keep the sex,"

It's important to note that HBO series in general do tend to contain a lot of sex and nudity. I've heard it said -- can't remember where -- that sex and nudity is actually there for the benefit of the female audience and not, as one might expect, the male.

I think that the adaptation to TV is rather true to the spirit of the books, though of course there are some things added that are remarkable in their randomness, such as the added character of a northern prostitute who goes to King's Landing and becomes a prostitute of Littlefinger's. I would not say that the TV-series contains *more* sex than the books, but they did keep a proportionally larger amount of the sex scenes, and just the fact that they are visual adds an amount of explicitness to them.

The same goes for violence, of course. It is one thing to read that a person's arm is cut off, and quite another thing to actually see it happen. As for swearing, I'm not quite sure what you are referring to, but it feels like you are talking about Robert. They did expand a bit on Robert's character, I feel, but that is probably necessary, considering that TV-shows are more literal in their portrayal of characters. I.e. it's not as easy to describe a person through flashbacks and dialogue, because people tend to remember what they see a person act like, not what others say about him.

Comment: I recently re-read the book while re-watching the show (i.e. watch and episode, then read the corresponding chapters).  There's a noticeable increase in swearing, sex, and graphic violence.  I can do this again and provide specifics if necessary, but I'd rather not. (Other than these, the adaptation is indeed very true to the book, which makes this change stand out more than where the adaptation was loose).

Comment: @TonyMeyer Would you give a few examples?

Comment: You already gave the example of the northern prostitute. That isn't just one example, she is used in multiple episodes, each use was an added sex scene. It seemed to me that every episode had at least one sex related scene, which only occasionally actually occurred in the book.

Comment: A co-worker of mine recently pointed out that there _is_ a lot of sex in the book, it's just subtle and easy to interpret as not being sex most of the time. His example was that in the book, a character showed up for an important meeting or something looking tired and disheveled - in the tv series, there was an explicit sex scene before the meeting.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - Excellent point on the POV characters. We definitely have more POVs in the TV mini series than in the book.

Answer (score 9):

I have read all five books. There’s more sex and nudity (if nudity is possible in novels) in the books. In the first book, Cat Stark is naked when the maester brings her the letter from her sister that says Jon Aryan is dead. Cersie Lannister gets naked many times in the novels, while I have yet to see her naked in any episode. Other than the prostitute everyone keeps complaining about, all other characters that you see naked are naked in the books too. If they kept true to the books there would be a lot more nudity and sex.

Now, I do agree that some things only implied in the books are shown on HBO. Renly and Loras was implied in the book, because we aren't shown either of their POVs. Things that happen when we don't see a character's POV can only be implied in the book; HBO doesn’t have that restriction.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - I agree. I'm a huge fan of the books, but I also understand the limitations of the TV mini series form. Ros was actually a brilliant move. They consolidated tens of prostitute characters into one, and used her to explore areas of the story not covered by the POV of the main characters.